# Display Joomla Intro Article without <p> tag

Tags: php, joomla

I'm customizing the layout of category blog view for my template and I need to display the article intro text without the

tag. In my custom file "blogalternativelayout_item.php", I use:

```
<?php echo substr(($this->item->introtext),0,75); ?>
```

Anyway this renders the introtext as

```
<p>Lorem ipsum etc...</p>
```

How could I do to remove the paragraph tags?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php `strip_tags()` function. eg;

```
echo strip_tags($this->item->introtext);
```

the code above will strip all the html tags in introtext.

If you want to strip tags except  tags, then you can put it like this:

```
echo strip_tags($this->item->introtext, "<a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use regex to achieve this task

```
<?php 

$text = substr(($this->item->introtext),0,75); 
//get the contents inside <p> tag using this regex
$result = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '', $text);

echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both suggestions. I've created this code and working:

```
<?php
$desctrunc = substr(($this->item->introtext),0,75);
$desc = strip_tags($desctrunc);
echo $desc . '...';
?>
```

Thanks.